# jquery/ajax "like" button not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

i have looked at the code but i can't seem to know where the problem is from

lemme drop all the required code so anybody could help

```
if($_POST['like_id']){
                $like_id = $_POST['like_id'];
                $like_id = mysql_escape_string($like_id);
                $id = $_SESSION['username'];
                $qry = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE username='$id'");
                $chk = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
                $uid = $chk['id'];

                $query = mysql_query("SELECT like FROM topic WHERE id='$like_id'");
                while($out = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                    $like = $out['like'];
                }
                 $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM likes WHERE topic_id='$like_id' AND user_id='$uid'");
                 $count = mysql_num_rows($qry);
                 if($count == 0){
                    $new_like = $like+1;
                    $query = "UPDATE topic SET like='$new_like' WHERE topic_id='$like_id'";
                    $qu = mysql_query($query);

                    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO likes(user_id,topic_id) VALUES('$uid','$like_id')");
                    echo $like." likes";
                 }else{
                    echo "<script language=javascript>alert('you already LIKE this message !!')</script>";
                    echo "$like";
                 }

            }
```

and the html part just the tag of the like button

```
<li><a href="" id="'. $output['id'] .'" class="like_button"><i class="icon-heart" style="margin-top:3px;"> </i></a><span class="like_show"'. $output["id"] .'>Like</span></li>
```

and then the jquery/ajax part

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(".like_button").click(function(){
        var like_id = $(this).attr("id");
        var datas = "like_id="+ like_id;

        $(".like_show"+like_id).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />');

        $ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../welcome.php",
            data: datas,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $(".like_show"+like_id).html(html);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

the welcome.php file is located 1folder before the header.php file..

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your `error console` on `chrome` inspector or in 'firebug` on `firefox` . Also,check under the `network` tab in `chrome inspector` to see if the Ajax call is being made properly

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$like_id = mysql_escape_string($like_id);
```

to

```
$like_id = mysql_real_escape_string($like_id);
```

You should also avoid using mysql_* functions, and instead use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo)

Answer (score 0):

**Dont use mysql_***

**Use PDO or MySqli_**

Comment: still getting a hang of it... all my codes are in mysql_ and i have about 1500 lines of php code...wuld take a weekend out to switch..but is there a way i can get it done without the PDO...

Comment: **use MySQLConverterTool** its best